# Angular Observable does not trigger function in subscribe on subsequent next calls

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am commmunicating between two components using a service and the Subject from rxjs.
But subsequent next() calls on the Subject does not invoke the function that I have called in the subscribe() method of my compoent.

In the code below, only the first call of component2 's methodToSendMessage(), invokes the doSomething() of Component1. 
Any subsequent invocations of methodToSendMessage() just does not trigger the doSomething() method.

Can anyone please help me on why this is happening ?

Component 1 is as follows

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(someService: SomeService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      someService.showMessage()
      .subscribe( msg => {
         doSomething();
      })
    }

    doSomething(){
      //the problem is this function gets called only once.
    }
}
```

Component 2 is as follows

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

   constructor(someService: SomeService) {
   }

   methodToSendMessage() {
       this.someService.notify(JSON.parse(""));
   }
}
```

And my service is as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService{

    public subject= new Subject<JSON>();

    public notify(res: JSON) {
        this.subject.next(res);
    }

    public showMessage(): Observable<JSON> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you providing the SomeService class? app.module?

Comment: Both components are in different modules.

Comment: did you tried directly subscribing to this.subject in your component1?

Comment: sorry @ManzurKhanSarguroh I am not aware of how to directly subscribe, I have shared a service between the components, to publish and notify. Can you kindly share an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subscribing to the subject directly

So component1 will look like

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(someService: SomeService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      someService.subject
      .subscribe( msg => {
         doSomething();
      })
    }

    doSomething(){
      //the problem is this function gets called only once.
    }
}
```

and your service will be

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService{

    public subject:Subject<any> = new Subject<JSON>();

    public notify(res: JSON) {
        this.subject.next(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: It Didn't work !! It gives me an error as TS1003: Identifier expected.

Comment: updated my answer, you just have to use type for subject variable
public subject:Subject<any> = new Subject<JSON>();

Comment: If you arent going to abstract the subject in the service implementation, then what is the point of having a notifiy method?